# Adding custom argument in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views, drupal-modules

How can i add a custom where clause in Views.
I have added argument field for User:uid, my requirement is to filter all the results except for particular user? something like uid != 1.

Can this be achieved using the PHP code option(Action to take if argument is not present >> Default argument type) of views..in either case please elaborate.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Get familiar with hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query). You should to use it I guess.

Comment: okies thanx.. but how does drupal uses PHP code option (mentioned above)... cann't i tweak that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 'Filter' to your view to exclude User #1 from the results.

Comment: Thanx Tyler..... what if i have some field which are not available in the list... actually i am using privtemsg module wherein i have to list thread count on number of replies? i can very well pull the values using the DB query but don't know how to implement same query through views.. it requiring some custom tweak?    Any help would be really appreciated... thanx once again..

Comment: I am not familiar with private message, but if that module does not expose itself to Views by implementing the Views API hooks, then some of the 'fields' provided by that module might not be available. If the module utilizes CCK then the fields should be available. Alternatively, you can create your own module that exposes those fields to Views for you. Check out this article to learn more about exposing custom data to Views: http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-tables

Comment: thanx for link Tyler.... i found one contributed module privatemsg_views which could be used let me explore it....